# Safari Extension insert HTML Code into Webpage with onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, safari, safari-extension

I'm creating my own Safari Extension which inserts 2 buttons into my DOM to improve the user experience on some websites.

I created an Extension using Safari Extension Builder. I created a script called `end.js` which is loaded after every finished HTTP request. In this script I check my DOM if a specific element exists and insert my buttons next to this element.

The buttons are created like this:

```
var headerElements = window.document.getElementsByClassName("headers");
if (headerElements.length > 0) {
    var header = headerElements[0];
    if (header.getElementsByClassName("button1").length == 0) {
        var div = window.document.createElement("div");
        div.setAttribute("class", "buttons-div");

        var button1 = window.document.createElement("button");
        button1.setAttribute("class", "button1");
        button1.setAttribute("style", "width: 150px;");
        button1.innerHTML = "allen folgen";

        button1.onclick = function() {
            alert("click button1");
        };

        div.appendChild(button1);           
        header.appendChild(div);
    }
}
```

As soon as I press the button only an error message is displayed on the console:

> onclick — end.js (Zeile 27) TypeError: alert is not a function. (In 'alert("button pressed")', 'alert' is undefined)

Why do I have access to all functions "outside" the `onclick` event, but as soon as the function is entered I can't access any of those functions? Even if I create my own function

```
function click() {
    alert("test");
}
```

and set the button's onclick to this:

```
button1.onclick = click;
```

I get the same error message.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's very strange. Just for kicks, did you try `window.alert()`?

Comment: It works if I'm using `window.top.alert();`. Very strange.